# Setting Cookies Enabled in Android WebView

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview

I am trying to set cookies enabled fro Android webview but its not working for me
Here is what I have tried

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
cookieManager.acceptCookie();
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();  
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);  
settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

And here is the JS

```
function getCookie(cname) {

    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    alert(ca);
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

### Update

Here is how i am setting up cookies

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {

    var domain = document.domain;
    var currentURL = document.URL;
        if (currentURL.substr(0, 4) == 'file') {
    alert("in offline cookie set");
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; path=/;" + " domain=file://";
      }
      else{
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; path=/;" + " domain=" + domain;
      }
}
```

Comment: Where is the cookie being set from? Each app that uses WebView gets a distinct, initially empty cookie jar.

Comment: @ksasq : I am simply setting cookies in JS just like in Online Browser..see update in in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you are trying to set file:// cookies. Please try this method, before a WebView is created or CookieManager accessed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(boolean)

Please read the documentation for this method!

Comment: Ahhhh finally... thanks dude, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Comment: Do you need to sync cookies from browser application (chrome) to webView, or cookies are not working just in webView. Have you tried to put `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` below `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);`

Comment: yup I tried it. I just need in webview. no other app  is involved

Answer (score 0):

You must call `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` **after** you initialize your webview. I think this is your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any documentation to refer to, but for some (perhaps security) reasons there is no possibilities to get Cookies from local file URL scheme (eg: file://...) through webView.

So I think the only solution is to build a local HttpServer (eg: [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)) an add a vhost for local files.